# Pass along state in an exception

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling

I'm somewhat new to ruby and I was wondering how bad of an idea would it be to pass along state in an exception? For example have an exception, that holds a list with all errors, that occured during a computation. Or would it be better to have the computation function explicitly return two things, a list of results and a list of errors if I know that things can go wrong?

Comment: Exceptions are rather slow to use them just to return values (or to control flow inside the object). Look at the [today's gist for example](https://gist.github.com/paneq/a643b9a3cc694ba3eb6e)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to reimplement Haskell's `Data.Either` or `Control.Monad.Error` in Ruby. Someone already did that: https://github.com/pzol/monadic#either